# BottomNavigationView, how to call a function on one item, and use AppBarConfiguration for the others?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

This is the normal way for configuring `BottomNavigationView` navigation:

```
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_months, R.id.navigation_due_date_calculator))
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

But, what happens if for one button you want to call a function and not to open a fragment?

I tried with this:

```
navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId){
                R.id.navigation_other_useful_apps -> {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Other Useful Apps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    true
                }
                else -> true
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when I add that method, then, the navigation is not working any more. How to call a function on one item, and use `AppBarConfiguration` for the others?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `onOptionsItemSelected` function, it will call the function instead of opening the fragment

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_other_useful_apps -> {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Other Useful Apps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

or try this

```
navView.menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_other_useful_apps )
        .setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem: MenuItem? ->
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Other Useful Apps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            true
        }
```